# Cómo validar si un registro existe antes de insertar en mysql con jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

estoy intentando validar si un registro existe en la base de datos antes de insertarlo y así no permitir duplicidad.Estoy usando mysql jsp y servlet. Tengo una tabla que se llama vlos, esta tabla tiene una primary key que se llama seq_vlos y es auto-incrementable por lo tanto este valor nunca se va a repetir, pero si el registro.Para ello estoy intentado validar por un campo único que se llama vlo que es un string único por cada registro y necesito poder validar que si intento insertar un registro que ya existe, el sistema me alerte.

mi proyecto esta en capas
tengo un package que se llama dao y en ese tengo las clases que tienen la consulta sql y tengo un package llamado controlador donde están los servlet.

y un package llamado negocio donde están las clases java.

aquí la clase Vuelo

```
   public class VuelosDao
{
        ResultSet res;
    Statement st;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    CallableStatement ct;

    public boolean ifExists(String SQL, String idBuscar)
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setString(1, idBuscar);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        return rs.next();
    }

    public void agregarVuelos(Vuelo v)
    {
        String sql = "";
        try
        {
            Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

            sql = "INSERT INTO VLOS(SEQ_VLOS,LNAR_COD_LNAR,NUMERO_VLOS,FECH_VLOS,VLO,EST_VLOS,TPO_TRANS_VLOS,FCH_CRE_VLOS,RUTA_VLOS)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1, v.getIdVuelo());
            pst.setString(2, v.getIataVuelo());
            pst.setInt(3, v.getNumeroVuelo());
            pst.setString(4, v.getFechaVuelo());
            pst.setString(5, v.getVuelo());
            pst.setString(6, v.getEstadoVuelo());
            pst.setString(7, v.getTipoTransitoVuelo());
            pst.setString(8, v.getFechaCreacionVuelo());
            pst.setString(9, v.getRutaVuelo());

            pst.executeUpdate();


            System.out.println("Insertado");
            pst.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {

            System.out.println(" No se puede insertar el registro" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

en esta clase tengo los métodos agregarVuelos que se encarga de inserta a la bd y un método llamado ifExists que debería funcionar para validar si el vuelo existe.

Acá tengo el servlet AgregarVuelosServlet que recibe la petición enviada desde el cliente

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

     try
     {

        Vuelo vo=new Vuelo();
        VuelosDao vdao=new VuelosDao();

        vo.setIataVuelo(request.getParameter("txtiata"));
        vo.setNumeroVuelo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtnumero")));
        vo.setFechaVuelo(request.getParameter("txtfecha"));
        vo.setVuelo(request.getParameter("txtvuelo"));
        vo.setEstadoVuelo(request.getParameter("txtestado"));
        vo.setTipoTransitoVuelo(request.getParameter("txttipotransito"));
        vo.setFechaCreacionVuelo(request.getParameter("txtfechacreacion"));
        vo.setRutaVuelo(request.getParameter("txtruta"));

        if(vo.getIataVuelo().equals("")||vo.getFechaVuelo().equals("")||vo.getVuelo().equals("")||vo.getEstadoVuelo().equals("")||vo.getTipoTransitoVuelo().equals("")||vo.getFechaCreacionVuelo().equals("")||vo.getRutaVuelo().equals(""))
        {
            String error="Campos vacios";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("error",error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            if(vo.getIataVuelo()!=null||vo.getFechaVuelo()!=null||vo.getVuelo()!=null||vo.getEstadoVuelo()!=null||vo.getTipoTransitoVuelo()!=null||vo.getFechaCreacionVuelo()!=null||vo.getRutaVuelo()!=null)
            {
                String mensaje="Vuelo creado con exito";
                request.getSession().setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("mensajeVueloCreado.jsp").forward(request, response);
                vdao.agregarVuelos(vo);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("<h2>Datos de formulario no fueron rescatados</h2>");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

por ultimo acá el modal donde está el formulario que envia los datos por post

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregarVuelos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAgregarVuelosLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header bg-primary">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalAgregarVuelosLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> AGREGAR VUELOS</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<div class="modal-body">
<nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center col-md-12"> 
<div class="left container-fluid">
<div class="panel-heading bg-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Datos de Vuelo</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<br>
 <form method="POST" action="agregarVuelosServlet.do" id="formAgregarVuelos">
<div class="container-fluid col-md-12"> 
<table class="table-responsive table-condensed">
<tr>
<th class="input-group-sm">IATA</th>
<td>
<select class="form-control" name="txtiata" id="iatajs" onkeyup="copiar()">
<option selected="selected">LA</option>
<option>M3</option>
<option>JJ</option>
<option>M7</option>
<option>UC</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
          <tr>
            <th>NUMERO</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NUMERO" name="txtnumero" required="usuario" id="numerojs" onkeyup="copiar()">
            </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>FECHA</th>
            <td>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="FECHA" name="txtfecha" required="usuario" id="fechajs" onkeyup="copiar()">
            </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>ESTADO</th>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="txtestado" id="idEstado">
                <option selected="selected">DISPONIBLE</option>
                <option>CANCELADO</option>
                <option>VOLANDO</option>
                <option>ARRIBADO</option>
              </select>
            </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>TRANSITO</th>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="txttipotransito" required id="idTipoTransito">
                <option selected="selected">CARGUERO</option>
              </select>
            </td>
     </tr>
         <tr>
         <th>FECHA CREACIÓN</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FECHA CREACIÓN" name="txtfechacreacion" id="idFechaHora" required>
            </td>
     </tr> 
          <tr>      
     <th>RUTA</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="RUTA" name="txtruta" required="usuario" id="rutajs" onkeyup="copiar()">
            </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>VUELO</th>
          <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigovuelojs" placeholder="VUELO" name="txtvuelo" required="usuario" readonly>
          </td>              
      </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>ACCIÓN</th>
          <td>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="limpiarDatosVuelo()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> Limpiar</button>

                    </div> 
                </div>   
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>  
</div>
</form>
</div>
</nav> 
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Acá dejo también el código de la conexión a la bd

```
public class ConexionMysqlCargomove_db {
private Connection conex =null;
private Statement sql = null;

public static ConexionMysqlCargomove_db instance = new ConexionMysqlCargomove_db();
public static ConexionMysqlCargomove_db getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
public Connection getConnection(){
        try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //conex = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cargomanager_db","root","");
        conex = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/airexpress_db","root","");
        sql=conex.createStatement();
        out.println("Conexion exitosa :)");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Error en la conexion con la base de datos"+e.getMessage());
        out.println(e);
    }

        return conex;
    }

public void desconectar()
{

 try {
if (conex!=null)
 conex.close();
System.out.println("Se ha desconectado correctamente de la base de datos.");


 } 

catch (SQLException ex) {
out.println("ERROR:Fallo al desconectar de la BD: "+
  ex.getMessage());
}


}

}
```

El tema es como podria utilizar este metodo en el controlador para que se muestre un mensaje que indique que existe el registro?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Hola dejó ahora el código modificado de la manera que intente hacerlo ahora y que me da un error de conexión y muestra siempre que el registro existe.

En la clase VuelosDao del package dao cree un metodo para validar sie l registro existe.

```
    public ResultSet validarSiExisteVuelo() throws SQLException
{

    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        String SqlValidarVueloExiste="";
        Vuelo v=new Vuelo();

        SqlValidarVueloExiste="select max(seq_vlos) from vlos where vlo = '?';";
        res=st.executeQuery(SqlValidarVueloExiste);
        //res.close();
        //"st.close();
        //conn.close();
        System.out.println("Vuelo"+res);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VuelosDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;

}
```

Y modifiqué el servlet AgregarVuelosServlet

lo que agregue al servlet es

```
                vo.setVuelo(request.getParameter("txtvuelo"));
            ResultSet resultadoValidacion=vdao.validarSiExisteVuelo();
            if(resultadoValidacion.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Imposible insertar ya que el registro ya existe en el sistema");

                    String errorDuplicidad="Registro existe";
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorDuplicidad",errorDuplicidad);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("errorDuplicidadMantenedorVuelos.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }
```

acá el servlet completo

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

     try
     {

        Vuelo vo=new Vuelo();
        VuelosDao vdao=new VuelosDao();
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        vo.setIataVuelo(request.getParameter("txtiata"));
        vo.setNumeroVuelo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtnumero")));
        vo.setFechaVuelo(request.getParameter("txtfecha"));
        vo.setVuelo(request.getParameter("txtvuelo"));
        vo.setEstadoVuelo(request.getParameter("txtestado"));
        vo.setTipoTransitoVuelo(request.getParameter("txttipotransito"));
        vo.setFechaCreacionVuelo(request.getParameter("txtfechacreacion"));
        vo.setRutaVuelo(request.getParameter("txtruta"));

        if(vo.getIataVuelo().equals("")||vo.getFechaVuelo().equals("")||vo.getVuelo().equals("")||vo.getEstadoVuelo().equals("")||vo.getTipoTransitoVuelo().equals("")||vo.getFechaCreacionVuelo().equals("")||vo.getRutaVuelo().equals(""))
        {
            String error="Campos vacios";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("error",error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {


            vo.setVuelo(request.getParameter("txtvuelo"));
            ResultSet resultadoValidacion=vdao.validarSiExisteVuelo();
            if(resultadoValidacion.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Imposible insertar ya que el registro ya existe en el sistema");

                    String errorDuplicidad="Registro existe";
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorDuplicidad",errorDuplicidad);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("errorDuplicidadMantenedorVuelos.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }

            else
            {
            if(vo.getIataVuelo()!=null||vo.getFechaVuelo()!=null||vo.getVuelo()!=null||vo.getEstadoVuelo()!=null||vo.getTipoTransitoVuelo()!=null||vo.getFechaCreacionVuelo()!=null||vo.getRutaVuelo()!=null)
            {

                String mensaje="Vuelo creado con exito";
                request.getSession().setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("mensajeVueloCreado.jsp").forward(request, response);
                vdao.agregarVuelos(vo);
            }
            }


        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("<h2>No se puede insertar el registro</h2>");
                    //String errorDuplicidad="Registro existe";
                    //request.getSession().setAttribute("errorDuplicidad",errorDuplicidad);
                    //request.getRequestDispatcher("errorDuplicidadMantenedorVuelos.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Pero siempre que agrego un registro nuevo, me dice que ya existe y muestra un error de conexión indica primero conexion exitosa y despues com.mysql.jbc.......

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se está callendo la conexión?
No está pasando por el if donde se valida?

Comment: `select max(id) where` y las condiciones de los campos más importantes, de esa manera me fijo que el registro no se repita, es muy costoso operativamente, es un problema de usar autoincrementales y no una clave combinada

Comment: Ok , pero no utilizo el id de la tabla de la bd porque es incrementable , en mi caso uso un campo llamado vlo que es un String unico, está como unique , y el problema es como uso el metodo ifExists para que funcione de acuerdo a mi modelo dao?  el metodo ifExists lo saque de una de las preguntas de stackoverflow, pero no se como implementarla en mi modelo dao

Comment: no fui específico, el `select max(id) from.... where vlo = "el valor a comprobar"` es para saber si hay una ocurrencia, ,si devuelve un resultset vacío entonces no está repetido, me explico? yo suelo hacer un método que hace esa verificación y me devuelve un boolean, lo pongo en un ìf` antes de insertar el nuevo valor

Comment: El campo  `vlo` como  lo generas? de manera aleatoria?

Comment: Hola buenas, ayer intenté de la forma que me habían indicado, pero no funciona ya que siempre indica que el registro existe aunque el registro a ingresar sea nuevo. Ahora me fue que calificaron mi publicación en -1 como  poco útil y quería saber que es lo que no se entiende? faltaron mas detalles, imágenes?

Comment: Kenneth el campo vlo se genera de manera aleatoria es un string es la mezcla de varios campos concatenados con una función de javascript , los campos son : IATA+"-"+NUMERO+"_"+FECHA+"_"+RUTA quedando así por ejemplo : LA-500_2019-08-01_SCL-LSC La ruta es SCL-LSC . ese código largo es el registro que lo define único , esto porque el id del registro es auto incrementable.

Comment: Hola , ingresaré nuevamente el código al final y adjuntare unas imágenes

Comment: Hola ya modifiqué al final , deje la forma de como lo estaba haciendo para ver si me pueden ayudar a resolver este tema por favor .gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías intentarlo hacer de esta forma, pero queda a tu criterio. Ejemplo en tu clase DAO crea un método `Static` para llamar ese método más tarde y pon el siguiente código.

```
public static int RegistrarVuelo(Vuelo v){
    int resp = 0;

    Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection(); // conexión a BD

    try{
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("INSERT INTO VLOS(SEQ_VLOS,LNAR_COD_LNAR,NUMERO_VLOS)VALUES(?,?,?)"); // tu agregas el resto
        pst.setInt(1, v.getIdVuelo());
        pst.setString(2, v.getIataVuelo());
        pst.setInt(3, v.getNumeroVuelo());
        int i = cs.executeUpdate();

        if(i == 1){         // Si hay cambios resp = 1
            resp = 1;
        }else if(i == 0){   // En caso no haya cambios resp = 0
            resp = 0;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        resp = -1;          // En caso de haber error en la conexión
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Entonces en tu `Servlet` después de **"validar tus campos vacíos"**, en el `else{}` pones el siguiente código para llamarlo.

```
int resp = VueloDAO.RegistrarVuelo(vo);   
if(resp == 1){
    String mensaje="Vuelo creado con exito";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("mensajeVueloCreado.jsp").forward(request, response);
}else if(resp == 0){
    String errorDuplicidad="Registro existe";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorDuplicidad",errorDuplicidad);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("errorMensaje.jsp").forward(request, response);
}else{
    String errorDuplicidad="Error en el SQL";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorDuplicidad",errorDuplicidad);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("errorMensaje.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Creo que es la forma más rápida de saber si un registro es duplicado y además también registra si no existen los datos.

Comment: la solución reemplazando ? por +vloVerificar+ ya la habia probado antes pero muestra el mismo error. Con respecto ala otra solución, la implementare y les cuento. gracias

Comment: Hola la segunda solución me funcionó  muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo que la línea:

```
SqlValidarVueloExiste="select max(seq_vlos) from vlos where vlo = '?';";
```

Sea cambiada por:

```
SqlValidarVueloExiste="select max(seq_vlos) from vlos where vlo = "+vloVerificar+";";
```

Donde `vloVerificar` sea el *String* generado, el identificador único de vuelo que pase como parámetro en

```
public ResultSet validarSiExisteVuelo(String vloVerificar) throws SQLException
```